# remove #div from url (external link)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have a onepage with a scroll menu. I want the same menu on my imprint site.
I want to link the menu to my main page but then remove the #div from the URL.

```
www.example.com/#div
www.example.com/
```

Can you please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use preventdefault() jquery function that should avoid to pass href value in url

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(clicked_elemnt).click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  jQuery("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 0
    }, 500);
 })
})
```

include jquery before above code

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var x = 'www.example.com/#div'
x.replace("#div","")
```